# Is there a Wine-like program, but for Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, compatibility, wine

Sometimes, there's a Linux app that I'd like to run in Windows (XP). Is there something similar to Wine that will do it?

Comment: Linux is FREE, why can't you just run it in a VM or just switch to Linux?

Comment: @LiraNuna: because not everyone wants to wait for a VM to boot up to run one fricken app or has found suitable equivalents for all their software needs to switch.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It really depends on the app. You can accomplish a lot with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), for instance. Especially if the app is command line.

I usually keep a Virtual Machine of Xubuntu (using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or VMware) around for just such purposes though. Easier, more features and full compatibility.

[Edit] You might also have a look at [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/). Runs a bit more integrated than the VM options.

Comment: +1, `Cygwin` it is.

Comment: cygwin is not anything like wine, as the app need be recompiled

Comment: My logic for suggesting cygwin is that source is often available. I've had reasonable success rebuilding command line apps (or finding them already in the cygwin 'repos')

Comment: Since Linux/UNIX is an entirely different ecosystem which usually requires recompiles even when changing from one platform to another that comparison is not entirely fair. It's only reasonable to assume a recompile on Windows too. Still, I'd prefer a VM to cygwin and if it were only to avoid having cygwin on my machine.

Comment: **andLinux** based on **coLinux**, and unfortunately they both **can only be installed on 32 bit Windows versions**, not 64.

Comment: @kirogasa - 2009 was a long time ago :)

Answer (score 6):

[coLinux](http://www.colinux.org/) can run Linux along with Windows.

As they say:

> Cooperative Linux is the first method for optimally running Linux on Windows and other operating systems natively. It is a port of the Linux kernel and support code that allows it to run cooperatively without emulation along with another operating system

Comment: [Note from coLinux FAQ](https://colinux.fandom.com/wiki/FAQ#Q27._Does_coLinux_work_under_64-bit_Windows): **coLinux can only be installed on 32 bit Windows versions, not 64 bit.**

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You could try running a linux distribution as a [Virtual Machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

One advantage of linux being Free/Open Source Software is that you can run it as a VM without any licensing issues. This isn't quite like wine, but should be even better in terms of compatibility.

Comment: Virtual Machine supposedly require more CPU and RAM than coLinux, but are good at a network support.

Answer (score 0):

Try virtual PC:
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx
If I remember right, the license allows you to use any older windows versions if you have a already a legal license for the 'host' system.

Comment: The link points to a 404 page...

Answer (score 0):

You could try a gentoo prefix installation in Windows:

http://blog.jolexa.net/2009/08/31/gentoo-prefixwindows/

Haven't tried it yet myself but sounds pretty cool and usable.

Comment: The link points to a 404 page...  [web.archive.org snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20091106012641/https://blog.jolexa.net/2009/08/31/gentoo-prefixwindows/)

Answer (score 0):

LIMO - very similar tool to coLinux.

Comment: Did you mean [LiMo (now Tizen)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiMo_Platform)?

Comment: Or [LINA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINA_(software))?